# Change column order for mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive, bulma

I want to rearrange the order of the columns once the browser width becomes 768px to make it responsive for mobile.
On desktop it looks like below, which is what I want.

```
[image0][text0]
[text1][image1]
[image2][text2]
```

But when on mobile it would look like the below. Which doesn't look too great, especially the parts with the star *.

```
[image0]
[text0]*
[text1]*
[image1]*
[image2]*
[text2]
```

How would I be able to make it like the below?

```
[image0]
[text0]
[image1]
[text1]
[image2]
[text2]
```

I uploaded the website here: https://yellowhexagon.github.io/. This pertains to the 3 images and 3 texts that come below the hero section.

I tried using display:grid and display:flex with order and couldn't get it for either of them. I'm using bulma.io as well so maybe there's a conflict between bulma columns. Overall, just quite confused and couldn't find much information online, so I would really appreciate any help. Thanks a bunch for your time!

Comment: Okay so I actually got it to do what I wanted it to do but I do not know why. Would still really appreciate it if someone could explain it to me. In CSS, I changed display to flex and flex-direction: column-reverse when max-width:768 in the parent div. This part I understand. But what I don't understand is why when I put class="is-4by3" in my figure element, that suddenly it doesn't work (in fact the entire figure element disappears). Anyways, thanks for reading this.